# Проблема с Rhel 8.4 при обновлении пакетов

Tags: linux, rhel

При попытке обновить или установить пакет
sudo yum upgrade
Получаю такое сообщение:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py:12: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 3.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Therefore, support for it is deprecated in cryptography and will be removed in a future release.
  from cryptography import x509

Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/yum", line 58, in <module>
    main.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 201, in user_main
    errcode = main(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 67, in main
    return _main(base, args, cli_class, option_parser_class)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 102, in _main
    cli.configure(list(map(ucd, args)), option_parser())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/cli/cli.py", line 829, in configure
    self.base.init_plugins(opts.disableplugin, opts.enableplugin, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 303, in init_plugins
    self._plugins._run_init(self, cli)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/plugin.py", line 151, in _run_init
    plugin = p_cls(base, cli)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf-plugins/spacewalk.py", line 79, in __init__
    self.activate_channels()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf-plugins/spacewalk.py", line 103, in activate_channels
    login_info = up2date_client.up2dateAuth.getLoginInfo(timeout=self.conf.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/up2date_client/up2dateAuth.py", line 229, in getLoginInfo
    login(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/up2date_client/up2dateAuth.py", line 196, in login
    li = server.up2date.login(systemId)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/up2date_client/rhnserver.py", line 67, in __call__
    return rpcServer.doCall(method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/up2date_client/rpcServer.py", line 214, in doCall
    ret = method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1112, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/up2date_client/rpcServer.py", line 48, in _request1
    ret = self._request(methodname, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rhn/rpclib.py", line 394, in _request
    self._handler, request, verbose=self._verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rhn/transports.py", line 177, in request
    headers, fd = req.send_http(host, handler)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rhn/transports.py", line 730, in send_http
    self._connection.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rhn/connections.py", line 200, in connect
    self.sock.init_ssl()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rhn/SSL.py", line 102, in init_ssl
    self._ctx.set_verify(self._ssl_verify_flags, ssl_verify_callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1103, in set_verify
    self._verify_helper = _VerifyHelper(callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 333, in __init__
    "int (*)(int, X509_STORE_CTX *)", wrapper)
SystemError: ffi_prep_closure(): bad user_data (it seems that the version of the libffi library seen at runtime is different from the 'ffi.h' file seen at compile-time)
```

Как обновить убрать эту ошибку?

Comment: Удалить скомпилированный Python 3.6 в директории `/usr/local`, таким же образом как умудрились его поставить (`make uninstall` в помощь: если сработает). И потом больше так не делать, никогда. Буква E в аббревиатуре RHEL означает Enterprise. Компилировать софт и устанавливать его не принято. Есть пакеты, используйте их в следующий раз, пожалуйста.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, таким образом я не положу всю систему? Я хотел обновить python2 до 3й версии. Поэтому накрутил.

Comment: Вряд ли положите. Всё что в /usr/local по сути несистемные файлы.